# Does differentiability imply convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

Can we say that if the limit of a sequence of functions is differentiable then the sequence is convergent?

I mean, I know that $\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}$ exists. If I specify a sequence based on the definition of the derivative, something like $f_n(x,t)=f(x+1/n,t)$ do I know that  this sequence converges just because the derivative exists? It seems so, but I am not sure.

Comment: If there's a *limit* for the sequence, it's convergent.

Comment: If the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$, then, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the main question:

No, define $f_n(x,t)=(-1)^n$.  We have $\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x}=0$ for every $n$, and clearly this converges (uniformly) to a differentiable function $0$.  However, it is rather obvious the sequence of functions is even pointwise convergent.

Answer (score 1):

You just said the sequence has a limit, so yes, it's convergent.

Comment: I edited my question. It will clarify what my doubt is